# Change event fired twice for kendo ui Combobox

Tags: c#, jquery, angularjs, combobox, kendo-ui

I noticed some weird behavior in all comboboxes in my application and after some time I noticed that the Kendo UI ComboBoxes are making or firing the change event two times and so they make two http requests if the code inside has one
I searched alot but found nothing to help

1. I use comboboxes with angularjs k-options (for general options) and k-on-change attribute for the change event handler
2. I tried to implement the combo box without angularjs attributes just as normal usage of the kendo ui combobox and it gave the same behavior
3. I didn't use alert for debugging this issue and used console.log for it
4. I used fiddler to watch for http requests and found that any change has two requests
5. I even tried and changed the requests to post and params to data but the same issue was found too

code sample:
html;
    `<select id="id" kendo-combo-box k-options="options" k-on-change="change(kendoEvent)" class="class" required></select>`

code in 'script tag'

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['blockUI', 'kendo.directives']);

app.controller("controller",
    function($scope, $http) {

        $scope.GetAllData = function() {

            $scope.comboDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({

                data: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.listFromC#)) // before loading view we're assigning the viewbag with alist of data
            });

            $scope.options = {
                autoWidth: true,
                filter: "contains",
                ignoreCase: true,
                placeholder: "Choose ...",
                syncValueAndText: true,
                dataTextField: "Name",
                dataValueField: "Id",
                dataSource: $scope.comboDataSource
            };
}
}

$scope.change = function (kendoEvent) {
               // kendoEvent.preventDefault(); // this line was added to test if it will prevent the second request or change event firing
                console.log('change fired');


            var cbAnother = $("#cbAnother").data("kendoComboBox"); // those two lines has no effect if removed
            cbAnother.setDataSource([]);

            if (!kendoEvent.sender.value()) { // this if statement has no effect if removed

                return;
            }

            $http({
                method: "get",
                url: "@Url.Action("Action", "MVCControler", new {area = "Area"})",
                params: { Id: kendoEvent.sender.value() }
            }).then(function(response) {
                    var dataS = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                        data: response.data.ourData
                    });

                    $("#cbAnother").data("kendoComboBox").setDataSource(dataS);
                },
                function() {
                    ....
                }
            );
        };
```

rest of code ....
i'm pretty sure I'm ending all braces right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it was a bug so I rolled back to previous version and it went great.